# Determinant of $2 \times 2$ block matrix whose diagonal blocks are zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices

$\Bbb A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, and $\Bbb B$ is an $m × m$ matrix.$\space$What is the determinant of matrix $\Bbb C$?
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{C}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
  \begin{matrix}
  0
  \end{matrix}
  & \mathbb{A} \\
\hline
  \mathbb{B} &
  \begin{matrix}
 0
  \end{matrix}
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
I thought it could be just
($\det\Bbb A\cdot\det\Bbb B$)
or ($-\det\Bbb A\cdot\det\Bbb B$),
but I'm not sure, as it seems too easy.

Comment: Well... what methods do you know to compute the determinant?

Comment: You might note that $$\mathbb C = \pmatrix{ 0 & I_n\cr I_m & 0\cr} \pmatrix{ \mathbb B & 0\cr 0 & \mathbb A} $$

Answer (score 1):

This determinant can be computed by the [Laplace expansion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion#General_statement) (the generalized form). Fix the first $1, 2, \ldots, n$ rows, and let columns range over $(j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_n) \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n + m\}$. Since the square minor is non-zero only if $(j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_n) = (m + 1, m + 2, \ldots, m + n)$,  it follows that
\begin{align*}
\det C = & C\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & \cdots & n \\
m + 1 & m + 2 & \cdots & m + n\end{pmatrix}(-1)^{1 + \cdots + n + m + 1 + \cdots + m + n}C\begin{pmatrix}n + 1 & n + 2 & \cdots & n + m \\
1 & 2 & \cdots & m \end{pmatrix} \\
= & (-1)^{n(n + 1) + mn}\det(A)\det(B).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

As Robert Israel [noted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3732109/determinant-of-2-times-2-block-matrix-whose-diagonal-blocks-are-zero#comment7672641_3732109),

$${\rm C} = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} {\rm O} & {\rm I}_n \\ {\rm I}_m & {\rm O} \end{bmatrix}}_{=: \rm P} \begin{bmatrix} {\rm B} & {\rm O} \\ {\rm O} & {\rm A} \end{bmatrix}$$

Let $\sigma := \det ({\rm P})$. Hence,

$$ \det({\rm C}) = \det\begin{bmatrix} {\rm O} & {\rm I}_n \\ {\rm I}_m & {\rm O} \end{bmatrix} \cdot \det\begin{bmatrix} {\rm B} & {\rm O} \\ {\rm O} & {\rm A} \end{bmatrix} = \sigma \cdot \det({\rm A}) \cdot \det({\rm B})$$

Note that $\rm P$ is an $(m+n) \times (m+n)$ [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix). It is also [circulant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix). Hence, its $k$-th eigenvalue is

$$\lambda_k = \exp \left( -i 2\pi \left( \frac{m}{m+n} \right) k \right)$$

where $k \in \{0,1,\dots,m+n-1\}$. Since the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues,

$$\sigma = \prod_{k=0}^{m+n-1} \exp \left( -i 2\pi \left( \frac{m}{m+n} \right) k \right) = \exp \left( -i 2\pi \left( \frac{m}{m+n} \right) \sum_{k=0}^{m+n-1} k \right)$$

Since $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{m+n-1} k = \frac{(m+n)(m+n-1)}{2}$,

$$\sigma = \exp \left( -i \pi m (m+n-1) \right) = (-1)^{m (m+n-1)} = \begin{cases} +1 & \text{ if } m (m+n-1) \text{ is even}\\ -1 & \text{ if } m (m+n-1) \text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$

Note that $m (m+n-1)$ is odd only when both $m$ and $n$ are odd. Thus,

$$\sigma = \begin{cases} -1 & \text{ if } m \text{ and } n \text{ are odd}\\ +1 & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

---

- Robert M. Gray, [Toeplitz and Circulant Matrices: a Review](https://ee.stanford.edu/%7Egray/toeplitz.pdf).

---

[linear-algebra](/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) [matrices](/questions/tagged/matrices) [block-matrices](/questions/tagged/block-matrices) [circulant-matrices](/questions/tagged/circulant-matrices) [permutation-matrices](/questions/tagged/permutation-matrices) [determinant](/questions/tagged/determinant) [eigenvalues-eigenvectors](/questions/tagged/eigenvalues-eigenvectors) [permutations](/questions/tagged/permutations)

Comment: I believe $\det P$ should be derivable through a certain permutation of rows/columns, without such heavy machinery.

Comment: @lisyarus That is almost certainly the case. However, coming from signal processing, I am more familiar with circulant matrices than with permutations.

Comment: For a permutation matrix, the easiest way to compute the determinant is via the [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants): $\det(A) = \sum_{\sigma\in S_n} \operatorname{sign}(\sigma)\prod_{i} A_{i, \sigma(i)}$. Since $P$ is a permutation matrix, all terms in the sum are zero, except for the one corresponding to the permutation represented by $P$ itself. The parity of the permutation here should be $(-1)^{m+n+1}$ if I'm not mistaken.